# Who is the odd one out?

Tags: pattern, knowledge

Nineteen of the following twenty famous persons share a **very distinguished** property, whereas the last one does not have this property:

> Albert Camus, Elias Canetti, Bette Davis, Nadine Gordimer, George Harrison,
>   Jimi Hendrix, Audrey Hepburn, Frida Kahlo, Jack Lemmon, John Lennon,
>   Doris Lessing, Marcello Mastroianni, Paul McCartney, Piet Mondrian, Pablo Neruda,
>   Pablo Picasso, Jackson Pollock, Elvis Presley, Andy Warhol, John Wayne.

**Who is the odd one out?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like this is too simple and might therefore not be what you had in mind, but, differently than everyone else on your list,

> Paul McCartney is alive

Comment: That was exactly the solution I had in mind.

Comment: But so is Elvis!

Comment: More like a very extinguished property!

Comment: According to an infamous hoax, all of them are in the same boat.